# Python create new column with top values (%) using other's column values

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I could not find function to get top n% automatically, so I sorted largest and smallest values and calculated numbers to make top 25% and min 25% ranges. What I want to do is to create a flag in new column saying that let's say this customer is in top 25% by revenue.

```
from heapq import nsmallest
top_max = avg_cust_data.nlargest(10806, ['user_spendings'])
top_min = avg_cust_data.nsmallest(10806, ['user_spendings'])

avg_cust_data['spendings_flag'] = np.where(avg_cust_data['user_spendings'] = top_max, 'Top Max',
                                  np.where(avg_cust_data['user_spendings'] = top_min, 'Top Min', 'AVG'))
```

Comment: What is `avg_cust_data`? If it is pandas DataFrame try `avg_cust_data['user_spendings'].describe()`

Comment: Yes, it is a DataFrame, but I want to create a flags into new column 'spendings_flag' and put values 'top max', 'top min' or 'avg' based on 'user_spendings' values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [`pd.qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.qcut.html)

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
avg_cust_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((16,1)), columns=['user_spendings'])
avg_cust_data['quartiles'] = pd.qcut(
    avg_cust_data.user_spendings, 4,
    ['Quartile %s' %i for i in range(1, 5)]
)
avg_cust_data
```

[image]

---

You can even customize the bin edges by percentile and the corresponding labels

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
avg_cust_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((16,1)), columns=['user_spendings'])
avg_cust_data['quartiles'] = pd.qcut(
    avg_cust_data.user_spendings, [0., .25, .75, 1.],
    ['Bottom 25%', 'Middle', 'Top 25%']
)
avg_cust_data
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
np.random.seed(100)
avg_cust_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((40,1)), columns=['user_spendings'])
print (avg_cust_data)


top_max = avg_cust_data['user_spendings'].nlargest(10)
top_min = avg_cust_data['user_spendings'].nsmallest(10)


avg_cust_data['spendings_flag'] = 
np.where(avg_cust_data.index.isin(top_max.index) , 'Top Max',
np.where(avg_cust_data.index.isin(top_min.index), 'Top Min', 'AVG'))
```

Another solution:

```
df1 = avg_cust_data.describe()
top_max_treshold = df1.loc['25%', 'user_spendings']
top_min_treshold = df1.loc['75%', 'user_spendings']
print (top_max_treshold)

avg_cust_data = avg_cust_data.sort_values('user_spendings')
avg_cust_data['spendings_flag1'] = 
np.where(avg_cust_data['user_spendings'] <= top_max_treshold , 'Top Min',
np.where(avg_cust_data['user_spendings'] >= top_min_treshold, 'Top Max', 'AVG'))


print (avg_cust_data)
```